# Getting text between xml tags with minidom

Tags: python, xml

I have this sample xml document snippet

```
<root>
    <foo>bar</foo>
    <foo>baz</foo>
</root>
```

I'm using python's minidom method from xml.dom.  I am reading in tags with getElementsByTagName("foo").  How do I get the text between the tags?  And if the tags were nested, how would I get those?

Comment: It pains me that someone is still using DOM, check out `xml.etree.ElementTree`

Comment: @serk this a slightly different question.

Answer (score 1):

So if you need to get the text out then you can do the following:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
document = "<root><foo>bar</foo><foo>baby</foo></root>"
dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(document)

def getText(nodelist):
    rc = []
    for node in nodelist:
        if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            rc.append(node.data)
    return ''.join(rc)

def handleTok(tokenlist):
    texts = ""
    for token in tokenlist:
        texts += " "+ getText(token.childNodes)
    return texts
foo = dom.getElementsByTagName("foo")
text = handleTok(foo)
print text
```

They have a good example on the site:
http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html

EDIT: For nested tags, check the example on the site.

Comment: You should edit this answer. The code sample is badly formatted and it doesn't work. One of the problems is that `getElementsByTagName()` returns a `NodeList`, which does not have a `data` attribute.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I got a little sloppy. Its all good now.

Comment: Yep, it works. But as @mikerobi says above, `xml.etree.ElementTree` is the way to go these days...

Answer (score 1):

Here is how with [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree):

```
xml='''\
<root>
    <foo>bar</foo>
    <foo>baz</foo>
</root>'''

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

for child in ET.fromstring(xml):
    print child.tag, child.text
```

Prints:

```
foo bar
foo baz
```