# Copy text from a specific point on a web page in Python

Tags: python

Say if I was given a web page, e.g [this](http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=True%20Grit&r=XML), how could I copy the text starting from `<root response="True">` and ending at `</root>`

How could I do this in Python?

Comment: By using an XML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import requests

URL = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=True%20Grit&r=XML"

def main():
    pg = requests.get(URL).content
    root = et.fromstring(pg)

    for attr,value in root[0].items():
        print("{:>10}: {}".format(attr, value))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

results in

```
    poster: http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxNjAzODQ0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODY2MjMyNA@@._V1_SX300.jpg
 metascore: 80
  director: Ethan Coen, Joel Coen
  released: 22 Dec 2010
    awards: Nominated for 10 Oscars. Another 30 wins & 85 nominations.
      year: 2010
     genre: Adventure, Drama, Western
 imdbVotes: 184,711
      plot: A tough U.S. Marshal helps a stubborn young woman track down her father's murderer.
     rated: PG-13
  language: English
     title: True Grit
   country: USA
    writer: Joel Coen (screenplay), Ethan Coen (screenplay), Charles Portis (novel)
    actors: Jeff Bridges, Hailee Steinfeld, Matt Damon, Josh Brolin
    imdbID: tt1403865
   runtime: 110 min
      type: movie
imdbRating: 7.7
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed it to urllib.request as well. Is there anyway to have it print out specific items?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for this:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=True%20Grit&r=XML')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
>>> list(soup('root')[0].children)
[<movie actors="Jeff Bridges, Hailee Steinfeld, Matt Damon, Josh Brolin" awards="Nominated for 10 Oscars. Another 30 wins &amp; 85 nominations." country="USA" director="Ethan Coen, Joel Coen" genre="Adventure, Drama, Western" imdbid="tt1403865" imdbrating="7.7" imdbvotes="184,711" language="English" metascore="80" plot="A tough U.S. Marshal helps a stubborn young woman track down her father's murderer." poster="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxNjAzODQ0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODY2MjMyNA@@._V1_SX300.jpg" rated="PG-13" released="22 Dec 2010" runtime="110 min" title="True Grit" type="movie" writer="Joel Coen (screenplay), Ethan Coen (screenplay), Charles Portis (novel)" year="2010"></movie>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the document with urllib2: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html

A good parser for short, simple, well formed XML like this is Minidom.  Here is how to parse:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html

Then get the text, e.g.: [Getting text between xml tags with minidom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653128/getting-text-between-xml-tags-with-minidom)